# Apache airflow sends sla miss emails only to first person on the list

Tags: airflow

I use Apache Airflow and I would like it to send email notifications on sla miss. I store email adresses as airflow variable, and I have a dag which one of its tasks sends Email using EmailOperator.

And here comes the issue because however It sends emails when my send-mail task is run to all the recipients, It do sends sla miss notifaction only to the first adress on the list which in my example means test1@test.com.

Is this some bug, or why it's not working ?

Here's my dag and airlfow variable: 
 [image: airflow variable]

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.slack_operator import SlackAPIPostOperator

email = Variable.get("test_recipients")

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow'
    , 'depends_on_past': False
    , 'start_date': datetime(2018, 8, 20, 0, 0)
    , 'retries': 0
    , 'email': email
    , 'email_on_failure': True
    , 'email_on_retry': True
    , 'sla': timedelta(seconds=1)
}

dag = DAG('sla-email-test'
          , default_args=args
          , max_active_runs=1
          , schedule_interval="@daily")

....

t2 = EmailOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id="send-email",
    to=email,
    subject="Testing",
    html_content="<h3>Welcome to Airflow</h3>"
)
```

Comment: How is question-related to SLA miss? I do not see `sla_miss_callback`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is currently a bug in Airflow when it comes to sending the SLA emails - that code path doesn't correctly split a string by `,` like task failure emails do.

The short work around right now is to make your variable a list (i.e. with a value of `["test1@test.com","test2@test.com"]` and access it like:

```
email = Variable.get("test_recipients", deserialize_json=True)
```

That should work in both cases (SLA, and task emails)

Comment: Just a short word of caution, while this works well in airflow 1.x, it will break in very non obvious ways in 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this as a bug, I would say it is an expected behavior. It is because you are passing a string `"email1@example.com, email2@example.com"` to `email` argument. You can do the following if you want to use this string as python list:

`test_receipients="email1@example.com, email2@example.com"`

```py
email = Variable.get("test_recipients")
args = {
    'owner': 'airflow'
    , 'depends_on_past': False
    , 'start_date': datetime(2018, 8, 20, 0, 0)
    , 'retries': 0
    , 'email': [email] # This will convert the string to python list
    , 'email_on_failure': True
    , 'email_on_retry': True
    , 'sla': timedelta(seconds=10)
}
```

In general, if you want to send email to multiple email addresses, you should always use a list and not string.

**Update**: I have fixed this in https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/3869 . This will be available in **Airflow 1.10.1**

Comment: yeah but why It's working and sends to all the recipients on failures, on retries and when I use it in EmailOperator

Comment: Yes, the code that is used for both is different and the one that is used for sla misses that functionality. I will try to debug and resolve this and create a PR, hopefully should be sorted in 2.0.

Comment: Isn't using Variable.Get in the top level a very bad practice?

Comment: Yup, if possible you should use environment Variable. Or use Secrets Backend via Environment Variable. For example, you can set `AIRFLOW_VAR_TEST_RECEIPENTS` to set an Airflow Variable via Environment Variables

Comment: Details: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/howto/variable.html#storing-variables-in-environment-variables