# multiple email Id's on Airflow email alert

Tags: airflow

#### Description

I would like my DAG will send an email on failure to multiple email id's.

#### My try

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'my-project-owner',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['email1@org.com', 'email2@org.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 2,
    #'retry_exponential_backoff': True,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 1)
}
```

not received an email with above arguments.

What is the way to mention multiple email IDs in case above arguments will not work?

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183511/apache-airflow-sends-sla-miss-emails-only-to-first-person-on-the-list)

This talks about various strategies to send emails for mutiple recipients.